# How to automatically copy new files to a network file share on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

I have a scenario where on a local C:\ drive a lab instrument creates measurement results. Newly created files should be copied automatically to a directory on a network drive, already existing files on this network directory should remain there.

Is there a builtin tool for that in Windows or does it need to be custom made?

Comment: [Robocopy "Robust File Copy" - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - check out the `/mon` and `/mot` options

Comment: You can also use Sync Back Pro and schedule runs every 2 hours or so. The capabilities are built into this app and no need to write code for it

Comment: Is it possible to simply write the files there to begin with?  It is clear from your question that there is connected access to the share at all times.  If the app won't take a UNC path, use a mapped drive letter.